# Quorum-maker-node not starting

Tags: blockchain, quorum, quorum-maker

I have created a node in quorum-maker using my ip address but that node is not starting.If i create a node using local ip(127.0.0.1), node starts.why?

Comment: Monisha, you can check the logs of the created node to see whats wrong. At a guess, I'd check firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

Quorum Maker by default gives you option to start the network with "N" number of nodes, join a network or attach node to any running network.
Please make sure that are you are using the correct IP address and port of the running node, while connecting to a network.